# Using Angular I want to show only selected options in sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

hi i am doing a project in angular material whaich have many components in side bar i want to implement a select option in side bar to show only selected ones.Any hint or reference to some documentation will be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Refer https://material.angular.io/

Comment: You can use Angular routing, see here https://dimitr.im/content-sidebar-angular-routing

Answer (score 0):

**as per your explanation:**  your sidebar is a parent component that includes child components and you want a way to communicate interaction with these children through the parent.

**resources:**

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

https://dev.to/riapacheco/parent-child-component-communication-with-angular-and-vanilla-js-1pae

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).